# Adding items in array and retrieving them fails to work

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I want to make a guess game with 6 boxes with HTML and CSS and then give each one a unique color.

I generate the colors in RGB, but it doesn't make the array and the array is just 1,2,3,4,5,6.

```js
var colors = [];
var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
function generateColors (num){
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random()* 256);
  var g = Math.floor(Math.random()* 256);
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random()* 256);
  var rgb = "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + g + ")";

  var i = 0;
  for(i; i <= num-1; i++){
    colors[i] = colors.push(rgb);
  }
  for(i; i <= num-1; i++){
    squares[i].style.background = colors[i];
  }
  console.log(rgb);
}

generateColors(6);
```

Answer (score 0):

There were few bugs in your code.

First of all, instead of `colors[i] = colors.push(rgb)` use `colors.push(rgb)`.

Secondly, you have to loss the new color with every iteration of the for loop, that's why you have to put the `Math.random` operation inside the loop. Otherwise, you will loss the same rgb every time.

```js
var colors = [];
var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

function generateColors(num) {

  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var rgb = "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
    colors.push(rgb);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    squares[i].style.background = colors[i];
  }

}
```

Comment: the blue part is still `g` and it should be `var rgb = "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";`

Comment: @AndreCanilho Exactly. Thank you!

Comment: The code for setting the background colors will never run since you have `return colors;` before it.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Sweet hint. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

your'e only defining each variable (r,g and b) once so they won't be 6 different colors. Also you geerate the color as a string. Thats perfectly fine for you to read, but css won't get this. Use the rgb() function instead, like this:`squares[i].style.background.rgb(r,g,b);`

Answer (score -1):

`r`, `g`, `b` values should be inside the loop for loading the colors.

```js
    var colors = [];
    var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

    function generateColors(num) {
      var i = 0;
      for (i; i <= num - 1; i++) {
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        var rgb = "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
        colors.push(rgb);
      }
      for (i; i <= num - 1; i++) {
        squares[i].style.background = colors[i];
      }
      console.log(colors);
    }
    generateColors(6);
```

Answer (score -1):

A few things. Optimize your cicles everytime possible.
Your generated values where outside of the cicle, so they were called only once.
You have a minor bug printing the "blue" part in rgb.

```js
var colors;
var squares;
function generateColors(num){
  squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
  colors = [];
  var r,g,b, rgb;
  for(var i = 0; i < num; i++){
    r = Math.floor(Math.random()* 256);
    g = Math.floor(Math.random()* 256);
    b = Math.floor(Math.random()* 256);
    rgb = "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
    colors.push(rgb);
    squares[i].style.background = rgb;
  }
}
```

```css
body{
  display:flex;  
}
.square{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background:#aaa;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
A
</div>
<div class="square">
B
</div>
<div class="square">
C
</div>
<div class="square">
D
</div>
<div class="square">
E
</div>
<div class="square">
F
</div>
<button onclick="generateColors(6)">Generate</button>
```

Comment: I would appreciate a comment over the downvote . What is the reason for that?